# build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, ubuntu, netbeans-7

I am using ubuntu, tomcat apache, NetBeans with java web based project. I am correctly able to default file of tomcat7 but trying to build a project; it is building correctly when I try to run a project I am getting above error. I didn't find any solution online found lot question like this, but none of them provide me resolution.

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error code as you and I am running GlassFish server 4 in Netbean IDE.
I just resolve it by cleaning and rebuilding the project.

For Netbean is just Run > Clean and Build Project.

Give it some time to do its work and ta daaaa! It just works for me. Do let me know if this works for you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the log file, that you type in Netbeans when you configured connection. Maybe Username and password are incorrect or someone in team modified it?? It's mine first published solution. It's good for most begginers. Watch video tutorials for more details.
Look here: Services/Databases/right click on (for example) MySQL connection and next Properties.

If basic properties are empty write username and password exactly that you use in MySQL database OR YOUR FRIEND'S username and password if he add new user for this project. See phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php for actual username and password. Login to database managing program for example phpMyAdmin and If it is different data for root user than in Netbeans change it twice in phpMyAdmin users tab and in config.inc.php 2) or create new user the same as your friend -ask him for details. You don't have to put new user in config.inc.php. So now you have the same username and password as in Netbeans. Make a connection to the table in Netbeans with new username and password (right click properties find user on list and add coma spacebar new user:  root, newuser). type and remember in program password for newuser. Disconnect table and base. Connect again and click Run project. Next time it will run with no bugs.

If advanced properties are empty watch tutorial for a program you use. There you can find exactly files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and I found a solution that is start from glassfish cmd administrator mode:
1. cd C: \ Program Files \ glassfish-4.1 \ bin,
2. execute asadmin.bat
after startup of glassfish.
START netbeans in administrator mode and execute your application, I hope that my answer will be beneficial for you.